# How to pass props from a connected component to a non-connected

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, components, react-redux

I have an outer component which is supposed to handle the connected props, and an inner component which is "dumb" supposed to get some of those props that come from redux. Is it possible?

I only managed to make the inner component work only when it was connected too.

This is how I want it to work, but I get an empty object inside `Autocomplete`.

```
<Autocomplete suggestions={this.props.admins}/>

...

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  admins: state.admins
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {})(OuterComp)
```

When I connect `admins` inside `Autocomplete` it works fine.

Comment: That is how it works, the connect just decorated the "smart" component and passes in everything you hook up in `mapStateToProps` in the `this.props`, so props.admin should be whatever state.admins is. Maybe you have something outside effecting this? Are you wrapping a router maybe? Maybe show more of the `OuterComp` component.

Comment: I do have a router but both of those components are very deeply nested so none of them should be influenced directly. Should there be a problem with what I attempt because `Autocomplete` is not directly connected to the state?

Comment: The code you are showing should work, so it's kind of hard to say. I would log to see whats happening in the OuterComp and the Autocomplete. Also - is that Autocomplete your own component? Autocomplete is connected to the state in the sense you are passing the state down into it via the OuterComp's connect. You should not need to connect it, something is going on outside of this code you are showing.

Comment: You need to check if the state is even changing and thereby props to Autocomplete are changing.
Also do check there are no mutations happening in state.